# Flag Question: Off-Topic or Unclear or too broad

Tags: support, flags

I just came about this Question, i think it should be flagged, but im not sure with what Flag.
The Post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179616/embed-private-website-in-wordpress-blog

It could be Off-Topic, but also Unclear (Does he ask for a Session System or how to imlement his System into his Wordpress Blog). It could also be flagged as Too Broad.

What would you do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a question meets multiple close criteria, it's not terribly important which you choose.  If one seems to be a better fit than others, or is a bit more specific, then use that.

As long as the reason you choose applies though, there is no *wrong* option.