# How much time should (new) users be granted to edit poor questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, minimal-reproducible-example

I've learned from higher scored users to ask (new) users in a comment kindly to edit their question if it's poor, i.e. that they shall provide a MCVE and example data.

Often these questions appear in the review later. Sometimes the comment is a few minutes old, sometimes hours old. I understand also such questions should be [flagged with *off topic: Questions seeking debugging help...*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293794/6574038).

Now my resulting question is, what the guidelines are, how much time we should grant a user to edit his/her code, i.e. to either **leave it alone** an other minute or to **flag** it?

Comment: Many of these questions are already downvoted once they have been identified as being of questionable to poor quality. Usually, once they downvote, they might leave a comment or move on, also the new user isn't taught how to notify them once their post is edited. Instead, I would suggest that questions from new users to require pre-approval - a negative-scored question can be thought as a question  being rejected and requiring editing.

Comment: Honestly it seems like it's up to you to vote. I've seen some people say they wait an hour then go. Others say they downvote immediately and then revisit one day later.... All in all it seems to be a very personal decision

Comment: There is no upper limit, any edit they (or anybody else) make re-activates the question and throws it back on users' Interesting page.  Regardless of how interesting the edit might be, a tag edit tends to be a bit underwhelming.  What is the point of this question, do you want a put a limit on it?

Comment: I've often thought there should be some sort of dialog that says something like `You have asked a question. Now, don't go away, people are almost certainly going to be asking for clarification. If you go away, you will almost certainly be downvoted or closed`.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous Actually this pre-approval feature already exists. IMO users should only be downvoted once they know how to ask.

Comment: @HansPassant If I wanted a limit I probably would have requested a feature. I just didn't find any discussion on this topic elsewhere. I am interested how others think and act concerning this issue.

Comment: I would say not too little time, but also not too much. Such questions are prone to be answered with poor answers and perhaps they should be closed before this happens. I wanted to hear how others act on this so I asked this question.

Comment: Keep in mind that the debugging close reason manly applies to debugging questions. How-to questions do not require an attempt to be on-topic, they just need to be well defined and reasonably scoped, which is a different set of problems.

Comment: I work the other way. Upvote an existing useful comment (or add one myself) AND Vote To Close. Then downvote if I find in an hour or so they haven't used the advice.

Comment: If OP's edit the bad questions before actually posting them, they can take as much time as they wish.  They will not be flagged or close/down-voted.  I'm surprised that more users don't take advantage of this loophole.

Comment: Related: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/2675154)

Comment: @honk Thanks. "You should wait for zero seconds. ... If/when the question is edited to become answerable it can be reopened" seems reasonable to me.